# How to integrate ccavenue payment gateway with android?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, credit-card

I want to integrate the ccavenue payment gateway into my rails app give some guide line for how to implement the gateway. I dont want to use paypal.

Comment: Please help ?????????????

Comment: am plan to integrate cc-avenue into android app for on-line sales please provide some help